# using _hashTypedDataV4 in smart contract and creating a hash function in web3.js to match the hash generated

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3js, ethers.js

I have a smart contract code that uses the _hash function below to generate a hash:

```
function _hash(string memory name) internal view returns (bytes32) {
    return
        _hashTypedDataV4(
            keccak256(
                abi.encode(
                    keccak256("Web3Struct(string name)"),
                    keccak256(bytes(name))
                )
            )
        );
}

__EIP712_init(SIGNING_DOMAIN, SIGNATURE_VERSION);
```

I'm creating a web3.js function to replicate the exact same hash:

```
function hashTypedDataV4(web3, domain) {
  const typeHash = web3.utils.keccak256('Web3Struct(string name)');
  const nameByte = web3.utils.utf8ToHex(name);
  const nameHash = web3.utils.keccak256(nameByte);
  const domainSeparator = web3.utils.keccak256(
    web3.eth.abi.encodeParameters(
      ['bytes32', 'bytes32', 'bytes32', 'string', 'address'],
      [
        web3.utils.keccak256('EIP712Domain(string name,string version,string chainId,address verifyingContract)'),
        web3.utils.keccak256(domain.name),
        web3.utils.keccak256(domain.version),
        domain.chainId.toString(), // chainId
        domain.verifyingContract // verifyingContract
      ]
    )
  );

  const messageHash = web3.utils.keccak256(
    web3.eth.abi.encodeParameters(
      ['bytes32', 'bytes32'],
      [typeHash, nameHash]
    )
  );

  const hash = web3.utils.soliditySha3(
    { t: 'bytes2', v: '0x1901' }, // EIP-191 version and transfer type
    { t: 'bytes32', v: domainSeparator },
    { t: 'bytes32', v: messageHash }
  );
  return hash;
}
```

I also have another function that uses ethers.js and generates the exact signature as _hashTypedData_v4:

```
async function signTypedData(
  verifyingContract: any,
  name: string,
  chainId: any,
  signer: any
) {
  return signer._signTypedData(
    {
      name: SIGNING_DOMAIN_NAME,
      version: chainId.toString(), // SIGNING_DOMAIN_VERSION
      verifyingContract,
      chainId,
    },
    {
      Web3Struct: [{ name: "name", type: "string" }],
    },
    { name }
  );
}
```

My goal is to generate the same hash in the hashTypedDataV4 function as the _hash function. However, I'm having trouble achieving this. I've tried different methods with the above code.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few differences between the _hash function and the hashTypedDataV4 function that could be causing the issue. One potential issue is the encoding of the name parameter.

In the _hash function, the name parameter is encoded using the bytes(name) function, which returns the UTF-8 encoding of the string. However, in the hashTypedDataV4 function, the name parameter is first converted to a UTF-8 encoded byte array using utf8ToHex(name) and then hashed. This could result in a different hash being generated.

To ensure that the name parameter is encoded in the same way in both functions, you can replace this line in the hashTypedDataV4 function:

```
const nameByte = web3.utils.utf8ToHex(name);
```

With:

```
const nameByte = Buffer.from(name, 'utf-8');
```

This will ensure that the name parameter is encoded in the same way as in the _hash function.

Another potential issue is the encoding of the EIP712Domain struct in the domainSeparator calculation. In the _hash function, the struct is encoded using abi.encode, which uses the packed encoding format. However, in the hashTypedDataV4 function, the struct is encoded using abi.encodeParameters, which uses the canonical encoding format. This could result in a different hash being generated.

To ensure that the EIP712Domain struct is encoded in the same way in both functions, you can replace this line in the hashTypedDataV4 function:

```
    web3.eth.abi.encodeParameters(
  ['bytes32', 'bytes32', 'bytes32', 'string', 'address'],
  [
    web3.utils.keccak256('EIP712Domain(string name,string version,string chainId,address verifyingContract)'),
    web3.utils.keccak256(domain.name),
    web3.utils.keccak256(domain.version),
    domain.chainId.toString(), // chainId
    domain.verifyingContract // verifyingContract
  ]
)
```

with () :

```
    web3.eth.abi.encodeParameters(
  [
    {
      type: 'bytes32',
      name: 'name',
    },
    {
      type: 'bytes32',
      name: 'version',
    },
    {
      type: 'bytes32',
      name: 'chainId',
    },
    {
      type: 'address',
      name: 'verifyingContract',
    },
  ],
  [
    web3.utils.keccak256('EIP712Domain(string name,string version,string chainId,address verifyingContract)'),
    web3.utils.keccak256(domain.name),
    web3.utils.keccak256(domain.version),
    domain.chainId,
    domain.verifyingContract,
  ]
)
```

This will ensure that the EIP712Domain struct is encoded in the same packed format as in the _hash function.

With these changes, the hashTypedDataV4 function should generate the same hash as the _hash function for the same input parameters.

Comment: thanks for the reply. when I implemented the changes, you suggested, 
web3.eth.abi.encodeParameters( [{type: 'bytes32', name: "_TYPE_HASH"},{ type: 'bytes32',name: 'name'},{type: 'bytes32',name: 'version' },{type: 'uint256',name: 'chainId'},
{ type: 'address',name: 'verifyingContract',},],
 [web3.utils.keccak256('EIP712Domain(string name, string version,uint256 chainId,address verifyingContract)'), web3.utils.keccak256(domain.name),web3.utils.keccak256(domain.version),
        domain.chainId,
        domain.verifyingContract,
      ]
    )
but it generated same hash.